# How to encrypt a string and save it in a file and read the decrypted string from the same file?

Tags: batch-file, encryption

I found an useful code on the net to encrypt and decrypt strings.
So i wanted to change it a little , in order to let the encryption and decryption in the same batch and not into two separate files here is the link [Batch Encryption](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/21566-batch-encryption-working/)

And here is my modified code:

```
@echo off
setlocal  ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
title Encrypt and decrypt string
color a
(set CHAR[a]=UDFM45) & (set CHAR[b]=H21DGF) & (set CHAR[c]=FDH56D) & (set CHAR[d]=FGS546) & (set CHAR[e]=JUK4JH)
(set CHAR[f]=ERG54S) & (set CHAR[g]=T5H4FD) & (set CHAR[h]=RG641G) & (set CHAR[i]=RG4F4D) & (set CHAR[j]=RT56F6)
(set CHAR[k]=VCBC3B) & (set CHAR[l]=F8G9GF) & (set CHAR[m]=FD4CJS) & (set CHAR[n]=G423FG) & (set CHAR[o]=F45GC2)
(set CHAR[p]=TH5DF5) & (set CHAR[q]=CV4F6R) & (set CHAR[r]=XF64TS) & (set CHAR[s]=X78DGT) & (set CHAR[t]=TH74SJ)
(set CHAR[u]=BCX6DF) & (set CHAR[v]=FG65SD) & (set CHAR[w]=4KL45D) & (set CHAR[x]=GFH3F2) & (set CHAR[y]=GH56GF)
(set CHAR[z]=45T1FG) & (set CHAR[1]=D4G23D) & (set CHAR[2]=GB56FG) & (set CHAR[3]=SF45GF) & (set CHAR[4]=P4FF12)
(set CHAR[5]=F6DFG1) & (set CHAR[6]=56FG4G) & (set CHAR[7]=USGFDG) & (set CHAR[8]=FKHFDG) & (set CHAR[9]=IFGJH6)
(set CHAR[0]=87H8G7) & (set CHAR[@]=G25GHF) & (set CHAR[#]=45FGFH) & (set CHAR[$]=75FG45) & (set CHAR[*]=54GDH5)
(set CHAR[(]=45F465) & (set CHAR[.]=HG56FG) & (set CHAR[,]=DF56H4) & (set CHAR[-]=F5JHFH) & (set CHAR[ ]=SGF4HF)
(set CHAR[\]=45GH45) & (set CHAR[/]=56H45G)
echo Enter a string to encrypt:
set /p Encrypt=
cls
set Encrypt2=%Encrypt%
set "EncryptOut="
:encrypt2
set char=%Encrypt2:~0,1%
set Encrypt2=%Encrypt2:~1%
set EncryptOut=%EncryptOut%!CHAR[%char%]!
if not "%Encrypt2%"=="" goto encrypt2
echo.%EncryptOut%>%~dp0encrypted.txt
echo.
set /p CryptedPass=<%~dp0encrypted.txt
echo Input string clear text ===^> %Encrypt%
echo.
echo Output string crypted ===^> %CryptedPass%
pause

set /p Decrypt=<%~dp0encrypted.txt
cls
set Decrypt2=%Decrypt%
set "DecryptOut="
:decrypt2
set char=%Decrypt2:~0,6%
set Decrypt2=%Decrypt2:~6%
set DecryptOut=%DecryptOut%!CHAR[%char%]!
if not "%Decrypt2%"=="" goto decrypt2
echo Input string: %Decrypt%
echo.
echo Output string: %DecryptOut%
pause
```

my problem is in the last part of the code ie the display of the string to  read the decrypted string from the text file? he shows me nothing ?
Surely I missed something? but I can't find it where exactly ?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

- If the `%~dp0` path may include spaces, the right file name can not be reached. Always enclose file names in quotes.
- The encrypt/decrypt is a *bi-directional process*. For example, "a" is changed by "UDFM45" *in encryption*, but "UDFM45" is changed by "a" in decryption. In your code you use *the same array* for both encrypt and decrypt processes. You must define two separated arrays: one for encryption and another one for decryption.

I fixed these problems in the Batch code below. Excuse me; when I use/modify Batch code, I don't like to manage certain Batch constructs, so I modified the code in the way I get used to...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title Encrypt and decrypt string
color a

rem Create Encrypt/Decrypt arrays
set "charSet=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890@#$*(.,- \/"
set i=0
for %%a in (
    UDFM45 H21DGF FDH56D FGS546 JUK4JH
    ERG54S T5H4FD RG641G RG4F4D RT56F6
    VCBC3B F8G9GF FD4CJS G423FG F45GC2
    TH5DF5 CV4F6R XF64TS X78DGT TH74SJ
    BCX6DF FG65SD 4KL45D GFH3F2 GH56GF
    45T1FG D4G23D GB56FG SF45GF P4FF12
    F6DFG1 56FG4G USGFDG FKHFDG IFGJH6
    87H8G7 G25GHF 45FGFH 75FG45 54GDH5
    45F465 HG56FG DF56H4 F5JHFH SGF4HF
    45GH45 56H45G ) do (
   for %%i in (!i!) do for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!charSet:~%%i,1!") do (
      set "ENC[%%c]=%%a"
      set "DEC[%%a]=%%c"
   )
   set /A i+=1
)

echo Enter a string to encrypt:
set /p Encrypt=
REM cls
set Encrypt2=%Encrypt%
set "EncryptOut="
:encrypt2
   set "EncryptOut=%EncryptOut%!ENC[%Encrypt2:~0,1%]!"
   set "Encrypt2=%Encrypt2:~1%"
if defined Encrypt2 goto encrypt2
echo %EncryptOut%> "%~dp0encrypted.txt"
echo/
set /p CryptedPass=< "%~dp0encrypted.txt"
echo Input string clear text ===^> %Encrypt%
echo/
echo Output string crypted   ===^> %CryptedPass%
pause

set /p Decrypt=< "%~dp0encrypted.txt"
REM cls
ECHO/
ECHO/
set Decrypt2=%Decrypt%
set "DecryptOut="
:decrypt2
   set "DecryptOut=%DecryptOut%!DEC[%Decrypt2:~0,6%]!"
   set "Decrypt2=%Decrypt2:~6%"
if defined Decrypt2 goto decrypt2
echo Input string: %Decrypt%
echo/
echo Output string: %DecryptOut%
pause
```

Comment: Great solution, i just added capitals charcters into variable charset
Thank you Aacini your solution is very helpful ;)

Comment: Wow! You did _two mistakes_ in your modification to my code: **1.** You inserted 25 additional characters in the charSet (you missed "X"), but you missed to insert the corresponding 25 additional encryption codes! Your modification leave all characters after "G" with NO encryption code. **2.** Even if you insert additional encryption codes for the additional characters, the method does NOT work this way. `set ENC[a]=value for a` and `set ENC[A]=different value for A` assign the values _in the SAME variable_ because Batch file variables are NOT case sensitive! I rolled back your modification...